# Simple MVC Route config is truncating action from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

Just when I was sure I understood how routes function, this issue pops up when I went to change the default route.

Here's the entire config (RegisterRoutes):

```
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Login",
      url: "Login",
      defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Unauthorized",
      url: "Unauthorized",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Unauthorized"}
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
  );
```

There is a link on the page that is generated using `@Html.ActionLink("Loan Management", "Index", "Certification", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { })`.

For some reason the output of that function is an anchor element with an href pointing to `"/Certification"` when it should be `"/Certification/Index"`. Other links seem to be generating fine (ones without "Index" as the action).

Why is "Index" being truncated from certification url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } \\right here
  );
```

That's why. `Index` is the default, so if you leave off an action, `Index` is assumed.

`http://localhost/Certification`
and
`http://localhost/Certification/Index`
are functionally identical.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. You're saying `Html.ActionLink` is omitting the "Index" even though I'm passing it to the function because it's a default value and therefore doesn't add it? It matters to my javascript code because relative links to actions aren't functioning correctly because they are replacing "certification" instead of the "index" that's supposed to be there.

Comment: Forgive me if I sound snarky, but it sounds like A) you do understand me, but you aren't excited about that answer, and B) you have a problem with your javascript rather than your routing. Why are you rewriting your urls with javascript? If you need to render a url, just let the `@Html.ActionLink` helper do it for you.

Comment: I'd forgive you for sounding snarky if it didn't seem like you were deliberately trying to be snarky; there's literally no reason for hostility. My solution is going to involve renaming "Index" to something else. My javascript code is just fine, thanks for the concern.

Comment: Alternatively, if that's truly a roadblock, just change the default action to an error page (or a 404). Then the `Certification/Index` route would be forced into being explicit.

Comment: @Slight Whoa, no malice intended. Just having a go at you b/c you clearly understood when you replied "I'm not sure I understand you." I do want to caution you about munging the urls instead of letting MVC handle the routing. Those helpers are there so you don't have to reinvent any wheels or introduce risk of error (which you've just experienced). Perhaps you have a legitimate cause for doing so, in which case I'd be interested to hear why.

Comment: Right, just because my interpretation of what you said happened to be right, doesn't mean I understood you clearly and didn't have to do a bit of guessing/inferring. All I was doing is confirming it. The javascript is using a "component" which takes a straight action name and does different ajax calls with it. It could probably be refactored to work properly with the full "/controller/action" url format, but the entire application is already doing it this way and in the interest of time, leaving it makes more sense. Each url should only have 1 representation anyway so it'll be fine.